# proguard causing EnumMap NPE on dynamically declared method

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm adding obfuscation via proguard/maven to a java application as we prepare it for distribution. During the process, it errors out with:

`Note: ...eventlib.EventManager accesses a declared method 'getHandlerList()' dynamically`

It then lists a dozen classes with that method with `Maybe this is...` and it recommends using `-keep` to avoid the problem.

When I do add `-keep public class my.package.info.eventlib.HandlerList { *; }` to the build process, the error goes away, but I see the following notices:

`[proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'events.TransactionEvent { TransactionEvent(my.package.info.inventory.Inventory,my.package.info.inventory.Inventory$TransactionType,my.package.info.inventory.ItemDefinition,short); }', but not the descriptor class 'my.package.info.inventory.Inventory'`

When I run the application, it errors out with an NPE (which it doesn't do when run without obfuscation):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:113)
at my.package.info.eventlib.HandlerList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at my.package.info.events.CollisionEvent.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

It's all tied to the events. How can I resolve this without telling proguard to keep everything tied to them?

Here's a full example of the original error: http://pste.me/m9BsY/

The event system is based on [lahwran's fastevents](https://github.com/lahwran/fastevents)

Comment: I don't know Proguard, but I would venture a guess that it is obfuscating `my.package.info.inventory.Inventory`, and `getHandlerList()` is somehow referencing it.  When the application runs, the required `Inventory` is missing because of the obfuscation.

Comment: It seems to keep recommending that I mark those files to be left alone, but I can't possibly mark everything that is involved with events, otherwise half my app would be left as-is.

Comment: Are this API libraries being called externally, I.E. from outside the JAR?  If so, then obfuscation may not be an option anyway.

Comment: No, they're classes that are used internally, but I supposed moving the event handler/manager libs to a separate lib is possible, while keeping the actual individual event classes... though I don't know if the existing classes will still break on or.

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard notes that your code accesses a method dynamically, but it can't figure out which method it is precisely. If it renames or even removes the method, the reflection in your code will fail, so you need to keep the right method(s). Maybe you want to keep all of the listed candidates:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    *** getHandlerList();
}
```

See the ProGuard documentation > Troubleshooting > [Note: ... accesses a field/method '...' dynamically](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)

ProGuard also notes that your configuration preserves the constructor of a class, but not all of its argument types. For some types of reflection, you also need to preserve these argument types. It's more likely that you're just accidentally keeping the constructor by using a wildcard. That would be a bit sloppy, but harmless.

See the ProGuard documentation > Troubleshooting > [Note: the configuration keeps the entry point '...', but not the descriptor class '...'](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)

For solving the NullPointerException, you have to know what is happening in your code in HandlerList. You can let ProGuard preserve line numbers with

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

If the code or the library performs reflection, and the original class names are important, you may need to preserve them. E.g. if the names of the event classes matter:

```
-keep class my.package.info.events.*
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same `NullPointerException` in the `EnumMap` constructor and could fixed it with:

```java
-keepclassmembers enum * {
   public static **[] values(); 
}
```