# Proguard Optimizer creates strange NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, proguard, optimization

Upon using Proguard's optimizer, I get a runtime error like the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Z.a(SourceFile:44415)
```

Upon using ReTrace, I get the following line as causing the problem:

```
temp = new EnumMap<anEnum, Object>(anEnum.class);
```

If I decompile the optimized code, I find the following code:

```
line 44414: EnumMap localEnumMap;
line 44415: 
line 44416: (localEnumMap = new EnumMap(dc.class)).put(paramdc, paramObject);
```

I don't really understand how this could be happening, nor what to do about it. The error does not appear without running the optimizer.

Comment: Enums and obfuscators/optimizers can be tricky (with another obfuscator, I had to edit the config file to make sure that certain enum-related methods stay intact during the obfuscation). Sorry, not an answer, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916025/proguard-causing-enummap-npe-on-dynamically-declared-method

Comment: Strangely, it only happens when optimizing. With only obfuscation on, there is no issue. It's only when I remove the -dontoptimize flag that the error is created. I've also added the proguard chunk of code for enums `-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}`

Comment: Well, no answers until now, so some handwaving: Obviously, the only thing that can cause a NullPointerException in the given (decompiled) code is the dereferencing that takes place at `dc.class`. Is it possible to derive (from the remaining code) what this `dc` is, where it comes from, and why it might be `null`?

Comment: Yes, the dc is an enum, like above in (anEnum.class). From the decompiled code: `public enum dc {
  static {
    { a, b, c, d }[4] = u;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

When an Enum class is used in combination with an EnumMap or EnumSet, its `T[] values()` method will be used via reflection to retrieve all possible values of the enum.

ProGuard will not detect this, and might remove some methods from the Enum class. This can basically happen either in the obfuscate or optimize step.

In order to avoid this error, you can do the following:

```
-keepclassmembers enum xxx.yyy.MyEnum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

This will prevent that the `values()` and `valueOf(String)` methods of the Enum class get obfuscated or removed.